# Unable to create an instance of LogisticRegression in Jupyter

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am using Windows-64 flavor of Jupyter 4.3.21. I am unable to create an instance of LogisticRegression class after importing learning_model. Below is my code snippet(along with error message):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lrn = LogisticRegression()
print(lrn)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2933c46e885b> in <module>()
----> 1 print(lrn)

NameError: name 'lrn' is not defined
```

But the same thing works if I run the commands on Anaconda prompt as below:

```
(C:\Users\ramu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3) C:\Users\ramu>python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
>>> lr = LogisticRegression()
>>> print(lr)
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: instead of print(lrn) try to type only lrn and see if it works. Also try to import the LogisticRegression only and see if this works

Comment: Thanks Sera. type(lrn) also results in the same error ('lrn' not defined). I didn't understand the 2nd part of importing LogisticRegression only. Is it something different to what I was doing by 'from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression'

Comment: No just type : lrn (without print or type)

Comment: Yes. type : lrn also results in the same error (name 'lrn' not defined)

Comment: The kernel may not be running in the env you think it is - check sys.executable. You can use 'jupyter kernelspec list' to see where it's finding information about the available kernels.

Comment: also how did you install sklearn? you need to open the jupyter terminal and install it and not just the command prompt

Comment: I installed Anaconda (Windows) 4.3.23 (thus sklearn was part of it - I didn't install sklearn separately). Running sys.executable on Anaconda prompt gives only one Kernel option which is the same as Jupyter shares.

Comment: The sys.executable from commands prompt shows the same path as the notebook shows ? Also make sure not to save your script with name like sklearn.py. This could lead to conflict.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is really very general. Try the following:

**Solution 1**

- Make sure that scipy is installed.

**Solution 2**

Type these in the windows prompt:

- $ /Users/abc/anaconda/bin/python -m pip install ipykernel
- $ /Users/abc/anaconda/bin/python -m  ipykernel install

**Solution 3**

Update conda and sklearn.

- conda update conda
- conda install scikit-learn=0.18.2

**Solution 4**

- Most likely your notebook has not loaded the right kernel (environment). The environment name is shown in the top right corner. If this isn't right, then click on Kernel->Change Kernel and select the appropriate kernel.

**Solution 5**

The problem could be solved by the below commands in the notebook.

- !pip install scipy
- !pip install sklearn

**Last Solution**

- uninstall sklearn and re-install